# Delete PDF from browser history

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf

I am working on an online application where the end result is the applicant can print PDF. I am showing the PDF in the browser tab using below code:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=something.pdf");
```

But the issue is, the PDF still remains in the browser history. Is there any way to delete it so that others cannot view it?

Comment: You cannot delete a history entry in a browser. JavaScript has no access to this functionality.

Comment: Create another account on the computer, have each user use their own account, this is what accounts are used for.

Comment: Thanks for the info..I wanted to confirm that we cannot delete the history. Once the user logs out, the token also expires.